# What is the maximum size of Static Json Document in Arduino JSON?

Tags: serial, esp8266, arduino-mega, json, buffer

I'm trying to do serial communication between Arduino mega and a esp8266, and having issues with determining the size of the JSON document. I have read that the receiver buffer size should be greater than the sender buffer, but what's the maximum buffer size we can use for the JSON document?

Answer (score 2):

The Arduino Mega has 8 KB of RAM, all of which you could use in a [StaticJsonDocument](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/staticjsondocument/).

The ESP8266 has 80 KB of RAM, but the [core limits the stack to 4 KB](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/eea9999dc5eaf464a432f77d5b65269f9baf198d/cores/esp8266/cont.h#L27). If you need something bigger, switch to a [DynamicJsonDocument](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/dynamicjsondocument/).

In both cases, you need to leave a lot of room for other variables and libraries. As an example, I wouldn't create a [StaticJsonDocument](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/staticjsondocument/) bigger than 6 KB on the Mega, and 2 KB on the ESP8266.

By the way, I heard this library is [very well documented](https://arduinojson.org/v6/doc/), did you have a look?
Do you know you can use the [ArduinoJson Assistant](https://arduinojson.org/v6/assistant/) to help you decide the capacity of the JsonDocument?

Comment: so you heard? :-)

Comment: Thanks and I checked the links earlier, but I have an issue, is the size we give when creating the static json document is in bytes? ex StaticJsonDocument<450> doc; is it 450 bytes?

Comment: Yes, it's the capacity of the memory pool, in bytes.